# Extract data from a Parametric2D plot

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to extract the data from a parametric plot via the following:

```
Subscript[\[Epsilon], e] = 0.0005;
Subscript[R, 0] = 15;
f[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
  1 + (4 Subscript[\[Epsilon], e])/(1 - 
       3 Subscript[\[Epsilon], e]) (Cos[\[Theta]]^4 + 
      Sin[\[Theta]]^4 (1 - 2 Sin[\[Phi]]^2 Cos[\[Phi]]^2));
x = Subscript[R, 
    0] (f[\[Theta], \[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]] + 
     D[f[\[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]] - (D[
         f[\[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Phi]] Sin[\[Phi]])/Sin[\[Theta]]);
y = Subscript[R, 
    0] (f[\[Theta], \[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]] + 
     D[f[\[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]] + (D[
         f[\[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Phi]] Cos[\[Phi]])/Sin[\[Theta]]);
z = Subscript[R, 
    0] (f[\[Theta], \[Phi]] Cos[\[Theta]] - 
     D[f[\[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]]);
```

Now, Parametric2D gives me the desired figure.

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 
      2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
     Mesh -> {{{\[Pi]/2, Directive[Opacity[1], Blue, Thick]}}}]
```

Next I need to save the data, and I do the following

```
data = Cases[
    ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 
      2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
     Mesh -> {{{\[Pi]/2, Directive[Opacity[1], Blue, Thick]}}}], 
    Line[data_] :> data, -4, 1][[1]];
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export["Groov_pro_Diff_THAf.txt", data, "Table"]
```

Through the above code, although I generate a txt file, I get the error

```
Part1 of {} does not exist
```

I have no issues with the plot, ParametricPlot[...] command gives me the correct figure, but not during saving the data. Here I would like to save the data as two columns only. Can anyone suggest how to extract the data in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such situations `Reap` and `Sow` are quite useful:

```
data = Reap[ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{{\[Pi]/2, Directive[Opacity[1], Blue, Thick]}}}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{\[Theta], \[Phi], x, y}]]][[2]]
```

This returns list `{\[Theta], \[Phi], x, y}`. If you want to save only `{x,y}` use it inside `Sow` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to save in 4 columns rather than {\[Theta], \[Phi], x, y} format. I'm do use "Table" while exporting, but it doesnt give the desired result.

Comment: That is you want only list of {{x_1,y_1},...,{x_N,y_N}} ? If so, using `Sow[{x, y}]` should work. For exporting indeed either export `data[[1]]` or in the definition of `data` use `[[2,1]]` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, Using Parametric2D I have encountered problem I now need to plot only the circumference points rather than all the center regions.

Comment: My answer was really about how to extract data from a plot. If you want to extract only some specific points, then this will depend on what exactly is your goal (I assume it is bit more than this example, as otherwise you'd probably just generate a table with points, rather than going through plot). Anyway, in this example you could use `If[x^2 + y^2 >= 15^2, Sow[{x, y}]]`

Comment: I didn't realize that the data will save all the points, as the Parametric2D fig gives me the circumference only. `If[x^2 + y^2 >= 15^2, Sow[{x, y}]]` does this have to be included after the `EvaluationMonitor` in the above example?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant: `data = Reap[ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, EvaluationMonitor :> If[x^2 + y^2 >= 15^2, Sow[{x, y}]]]][[2, 1]]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thanks